# CSS3 Media query is not working

Tags: css, media-queries

So I'm trying to make my website responsive. I have a few media queries. The first one is not contained within media queries because it's less than 768px, which is for mobile phones. And then I have another with @media (min-width: 768px) {} and @media (min-width: 1200px) {}.

However, I added a box-shadow around a div to the mobile version and for some reason the box-shadow is still appearing around the div when the screen is more than 768px, it's still there. Do you know why this is happening?

Here's just an example of how I have it.

#### HTML

```
<div>CONTENT</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
      div {/* I got rid of box shadow, but it's still displaying on screens higher than 768px */
       }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   div { /* I got rid of box shadow, but it's still displaying on screens higher than 1200px */
   }
}
```

Comment: have you added meta tag for media queries? share complete code, then we can figure out exact problem.

Comment: Yes I have added the meta tag. Everything is working fine, except that box-shadow around the div on bigger screens when it shouldn't be there in the first place. And the code is similar to what I posted up there to make it simple. It's just the box-shadow that's giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
```

Comment: Do I want to use max-width? Since I'm just starting out, I was told it's more convenient to use min-width instead of max-width. So you're saying I should have max-width for only 768px and leave min width for the 1200px?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need max-width: 768px, instead of min-width

Comment: For just 768px or 1200px as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by just changing the first `min-width` to `max-width`. But also I would change the second media-query to apply to everything over 768px or set a media-query wich apply‘s only from 769px to 1199px and a media-query for everything over that.

**Here‘s an example:**

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    div {
   
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    div {

    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    div {
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I find sometimes media queries just won't work for me for whatever reason, instead you can use jQuery as such:

```
<script>//mobile responsiveness
var width = jQuery(window).width();
function ipad() {
if (width <= 1024 && width >= 768){ //if tablet
//css here

} else if (width < 768){  //if mobile phone
//css here
}
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
ipad();//run when page first loads
});

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
ipad();//run on every window resize
});
</script>
```

Comment: That would be awesome, however, I was given a website challenge by a startup and I was told not to use javascript at all. Only CSS3 and HTML5. I appreciate your help though, I will use this for future reference.

Comment: Jquery is completely unnecessary for this problem and just overcomplicates things